# Program using /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

The file is configured for a static ip ethernet connection. I do not have isc-dhcp-client nor network-manager. So which is the program that actually uses /etc/network/interfaces to make the connection ? Is it the Linux kernel directly ?

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.190
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't the kernel. /etc/network/interfaces is just a configuration file used by ifup and ifdown, which are scripts run as part of the startup sequence, usually by a service with the word "network" somewhere in it. If you google around for [Ubuntu Startup Sequence](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu%20startup%20sequence), you'll find some decent descriptions about how startup works and from there you can figure out exactly what happens for the particular version you are running.

Comment: Once the network is up, which is the program that handles ethernet traffic ?

Comment: @WarrenJackson Once the Ethernet connection is up, and the interface is provisioned with IP information, it is the kernel that handles traffic through the sockets interface.

Answer (score 1):

Not the kernel, the kernel doesn't read your filesystem.
There are some scripts (for ex /etc/init.d/networking), which process this file and via kernel API calls will raise the devices, configure IP's/route's etc.

Comment: Once the network is up, which is the program that handles ethernet traffic ?

Comment: Kernel handles.